# Android External storage handle unavailability

Tags: android, file, storage, external

In my app the user can save screenshots and files in his external storage. But what shall I do when the external storage is not writeable? I had this issue when updating my device from lollipop to marshmallow. The sd-card did not get recognized by my app when I tried to save a screenshot. But it was accessable by ES Filex Explorer but READ-ONLY! Shouldnt there be a part of the internal storage that is reserved as "external" storage on every device? Why did this not work?

*P.S. The code works well when external storage is writeable!*

Thats my code:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = getScreenshotFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        File file = storeImage(bitmap, name);
        if(file != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.screenshotSaved, name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.toURI().toString()), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.notAvailable), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



     private File storeImage(Bitmap image, String name) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(name);
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                System.out.println("Error A");
            }else{
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error B");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error C");
                }
            }

            return pictureFile;
        }

private File getOutputMediaFile(String name){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(new Helper(this).getPathToAppFolder());

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name#
        File mediaFile;
        if(!name.equals(getString(R.string.training))){
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy_HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            String mImageName= name + "_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
        }else{
            String mImageName= name + ".jpg";
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Comment: Every device has external storage. And every app can write to it with the write external storage permission requested in manifest. If you add a micro SD card then on this removable storage there is mostly no writing possible. Its unclear where you are talking about.

Comment: `user can save screenshots and files in his external storage`. Is it? Nobody can check your code as we dont know what `new Helper(this).getPathToAppFolder()` delivers.

Comment: It worked well on lollipop.  public String getPathToAppFolder(){
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/Files/";
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ask for permissions Marshmallow style, see here for more: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Permissions#permission-updates-in-marshmallow

Before running file save operations you'll need to check if the permissions is accepted, if not, you decide what makes sense for your app to have a "graceful" failure.

Comment: do i have to ask ones or always?

Comment: Always is the correct way. Users can revoke permission at any time so you need to be able to handle that to avoid crashes related to permissions.

Answer (score 1):

From the Marshmallow you need to ask permission manually to the user for write/read the phone storage.

see this example or use this [example](https://androidexampleblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/androids-runtime-permission-example/) to ask Permission Manually.